# error while giving multiple options for the back key in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I'm developing a game in libgdx . I have enabled the back key for the game which provides two option. One is while pressing the back button one pop up menu will come and ask for the "Confirm to exit ". If press yes the game will resume but if the back button press again the pop-up menu should disappear. but in my game, while pressing the back button again the  game is not Resuming .iIt simply render the pop-up menu again and again . I have tried with the boolean but it's not happening . I hope somebody can help me. Here I'm posting some of the code

```
      public void update(){

       if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)) {

        worldController.isPaused = true;


     }

     if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)&&worldController.isPaused = true){
    worldController.isPaused = false;
     } 
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the event will continuously run while the key is pressed. This is probably not the behaviour you want and instead you want to check if the key was pressed once and upon that perform an action.

You can use [isKeyJustPressed](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#isKeyJustPressed-int-) for this purpose.

```
public void update() {

   if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.BACK)) {

      // Flip the boolean value
      worldController.isPaused = !worldController.isPaused;
   }
}
```